# Java WebStart deployJava.runApplet keeps reloading

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

When a client PC is not installed with the Java, the below code leads to the Java installation page.

I canceled the installation, and reconnect to the html below.

Now it recursively calls the html page and Java installation pop up appears.

Anyone can try with below code only.

Is it deployJava.js's bug?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = { code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet',  width:710, height:540} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'download/_local_pkitoolkit.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7'); 

</script>   
</head>
<body bgcolor="#B4B4B4">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Since an applet element in the head is not allowed, that HTML is not valid. 2) What is your question?  3) The behavior you describe seems quite logical for the script, but quite illogical for the user.  We cannot debug users on SO.

Comment: If I put the script in window.onload function, it only calls the html once. The runapplet calls documnet.writeln(), and deployJava.js says below. Should it be the reason? Pretty format of the js file is http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt.  As document.writeln() is generally only safe to use while the page is being rendered, you should never call this function after the page has been completed.